# HttpResponse namespace/prefix does not match with the WSDL format on Serializing the XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, wsdl, httpresponse

**Current Response**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header />
    <s:Body>
        <CreateCaseResponse xmlns="http://">
            <CreateCaseResult>
                <ErrorMessage>\n</ErrorMessage>
                <Successful>true</Successful>
                <CaseNumber></CaseNumber>
                <Recno></Recno>
            </CreateCaseResult>
        </CreateCaseResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

In the above response, `CreateCaseResult` does not have the `namespace` and also the data member `(CaseNumber and Recno)` are missing the `prefix` when compared with the `expected response` below.

**Expected response**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <CreateCaseResponse xmlns="">
         <CreateCaseResult xmlns:a="" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ErrorDetails i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessage></ErrorMessage>
            <Successful>true</Successful>
            <a:CaseNumber></a:CaseNumber>
            <a:Recno></a:Recno>
         </CreateCaseResult>
      </CreateCaseResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**Code for Serializing is as below -**

```
 private static string MakeSerializedWithSoapEnvelope(object obj, string defaultNamespace)
        {
            var respFormat = @"
<s:Envelope xmlns:s=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    {0}
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>";

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), defaultNamespace);
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.Indent = true;
            

            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("", defaultNamespace);

            using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter, settings))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, obj, ns);
                    return string.Format(respFormat, stringWriter.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Here `defaultNamespace` is passed as ``.

Please help me on what changes to the code should be done to get the `desired and expected output/response.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the serializer does not know by itself that there are multiple namespaces in the object that he needs to serialize. You specify the default namespace and that is what the serializer is adding to  all the content. If you need more namespaces on specific elements it may be better to define the to be serialized object in a class and add xml serialization information to the specific elements.

Comment: @martijn can i have an example on this one please?

Comment: See the answer that @jdweng has provided. this will give you all the guidance you need to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;


namespace ConsoleApplication169
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
            ns.Add("s", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            ns.Add("", "http://software-innovation.com/SI.Data");
            ns.Add("a", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SI.Data.Contracts.WS");
            ns.Add("i", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

            Envelope envelope = new Envelope();
            Body body = new Body();
            envelope.Body = body;
            CreateCaseResult results = new CreateCaseResult();
            body.CreateCaseResult = new List<CreateCaseResult>() { results};
            results.ErrorDetails = new Detail() { nil = true };

            results.Successful = true;
            results.CaseNumber = "20/00239";
            results.Recno = "200245";
            results.ErrorMessage = "";

            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, envelope, ns);
 

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlArray(ElementName = "CreateCaseResponse", Namespace = "")]
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "CreateCaseResult", Namespace = "")]
        public List<CreateCaseResult> CreateCaseResult { get; set; }
    }
    public class CreateCaseResult 
    {
        public Detail ErrorDetails { get; set; }
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
        public Boolean Successful { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "CaseNumber", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SI.Data.Contracts.WS")]
        public string CaseNumber { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Recno", Namespace = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SI.Data.Contracts.WS")]
        public string Recno { get; set; }
    }
    public class Detail
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "nil", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
        public Boolean nil { get; set; }
    }
}
```